# Enumerate environments in abstract

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, abstract

Consider usage of the standard `enumerate` environment inside the standard (`article`) `abstract` environment:

```
\begin{abstract}
  We discuss several exciting topics:
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Topic 1, explained at such length that the text produces a line break,
  \item Topic 2.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{abstract}
```

My complaint is that the `enumerate` environment doesn't respect the margin reductions of the abstract environment. (In particular, the index numbers appear to the left of the left margin, and the text is wrapped to right of the right margin.)

Presumably, I could wrap the `enumerate` environment in a `minipage` to control the margins by brute force. What is the right way to do it?

To elaborate on the question, you can see an example below:
[image]

You may notice that this was not produced from the article class. The class does, however, borrow the abstract code (with some--I thought--insignificant changes) from the conventional article class.

Comment: @Alexander Russell: Don't do this. Instead, say "We discuss several exciting topics. Firstly, we consider topic 1: we have shown by ... that ... and discuss the possibility that ... Secondly, we determined that ... in topic 2."

Comment: although it's maybe not the best style, *some* document classes do honor the margins set for the abstract when an `enumerate` is present.  `amsart` is one such.  perhaps you could crib some code from that.  (i haven't explored to see how difficult it might be.)  i think the problem was addressed there because sometimes numbered displays are embedded in the abstract, and the margins have to be honored for those.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your responses. While I agree that this sort of usage may not be ideal, stylistically, in an abstract, the issue came up while writing a class file for a journal so I'd naturally like the abstract environment to be as robust as possible. Thanks for the pointer to the amsart class!

Comment: @AlexanderRussell Sorry, I implicitly assumed in my comment that you were choosing to write the abstract in that way. I hope you didn't take it personally.

Comment: I think the problem does not lie with the `abstract` environment (or code), but rather with your `enumerate` code. Without the actual class code, it would be hard to assess how to fix your current situation.

Comment: @AlexanderRussell Please consider to upvote helpful answers (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it) and to accept the most helpful one (by clicking on the checkmark).

Comment: Dear lockstep & @Werner, Thanks to both of you. It appears that I will have to carefully contrast the abstract code in my class file with that in the conventional article.cls file to figure out the problem: as lockstep pointed out, the conventional article.cls appears to have the right behavior.

Comment: OP states that the issue is a flaw in his custom `.sty` file, so closing as 'too localised'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"My complaint is that the enumerate environment doesn't respect the margin reductions of the abstract environment. (In particular, the index numbers appear to the left of the left margin, and the text is wrapped to right of the right margin.)"*

In the `article` class, list environments like `enumerate` *do* respect the margin reductions of the `abstract` environment -- have a look at my example. (You may have mistakened the indentation of the abstract's first line with a general indentation of the environment's left margin.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Topic 1, explained at such length that the text \emph{really} 
produces a line break,
  \item Topic 2.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{abstract}

\section{foo}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @lockstep, This is embarrassing. As you point out, the abstract environment in the current version of the article class _does_ produce robust enough margins for the enumerate to respect. This means that I have some problem in my own custom class that I shouldn't be blaming on article.cls! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you really *must* use a list environment in your `abstract`, I suggest using the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to manage the horizontal spacing or margins. Note that the output from your code snippet produces results as expected, since the "first paragraph" (starting with "We discuss...") is actually indented by a length `\parindent`. Either way, here is a take on a possibility that you might be after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
  We discuss several exciting topics:
  \begin{enumerate}[label={Topic~\arabic*:},leftmargin=*]
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \item \lipsum[3]
  \end{enumerate}
  And here we have the end of the abstract.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
​
```

Some more things to note:

- Since `\lipsum` typesets paragraphs, it issues `\par` at the end of every paragraph. This makes the following paragraph indent by `\parindent`, as you can see from the MWE.
- Since there is no gap between the end of the `enumerate` environment and the start of the last sentence/paragraph, no `\parindent` is visible. If you want a paragraph indent, issue `\par` at the end of `enumerate`, or use `\indent`.
- I've made the list enumerate itself as `Topic~\arabic*:` by using the functionality of `enumitem`'s `label` setting.
- Also, making the left margin flush with the text block (in `abstract`), I've used `leftmargin=*`. Other alignment options are also available.

[`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was used to highlight the text block margins, while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided some dummy text.

---

In an attempt to replicate your abstract *without* any package dependencies, consider the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
This paper studies the one-way communication complexity of the \textit{subgroup
membership problem\/}, a classical problem closely related to basic questions in quantum
computing. Here Alice receives, as input, a subgroup~$H$ of a finite group~$G$; Bob receives
an element $y\in G$. Alice is permitted to send a single message to Bob, after which he must
decide if his input~$y$ is an element of~$H$. We establish the following bounds on the classical
communication complexity of this problem in the bounded-error setting: \par \medskip

\addtolength{\leftskip}{1.5em} \setlength{\parindent}{-1.5em}

\makebox[1.5em][l]{1.}The problem can be solved with $\mathcal{O}(\log|G|)$-bit communication with the promise that~$H$ is normal. \par \medskip

\makebox[1.5em][l]{2.}The problem can be solved with $\mathcal{O}(d_{\max}-\log|G|)$-bit communication, where~$d_{\max}$ is the maximum
degree of an irreducible complex representation of~$G$. \par \medskip

\makebox[1.5em][l]{3.}For any prime~$p$ not dividing~$|G|$, the problem can be solved with $\mathcal{O}(\log|G|+d_{\max}\cdot\log p)$-bit
communication, where~$d_{\max}$ is the maximum degree of an irreducible $\mathbf{F}_p$-representation of~$G$.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

This way you typeset an enumeration by physically adjusting the left margin (`\leftskip`) and accompanying paragraph indent (`\parindent`) to simulate `enumerate`. I've hardcoded the numbering, but that can be made into a counter as well. However, this would only be necessary if they may be re-ordered often, or if you want to reference them by means of `\label` and `\ref` commands. Also, I've placed a `\medskip` between the items to make it look like an enumeration. However, a single `\par` would also suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your very complete response. I can see from your example that the enumitem package is rich enough to solve the problem. In my particular case (which I did not explain above), this is for a class file for a journal. I would like to keep package dependencies to a minimum, so if I can actually rewrite the abstract code to make it more robust, I would be more satisfied with that solution.

Comment: @AlexanderRussell: I've added a hard-coded version of you abstract that simulates the `enumerate` environment. It is independent of any packages, and should therefore fit nicely with your current document class.